# Using Join with Where

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have following tables.

```
Table Name: Recipe
id  topic    description    difficultylevel     totaltime
1   Cheese   Cheese         Easy                10
2   Cheese1  Cheese1        Medium              50

Table Name: Ingredients
id  recipeid    ingredient
1   1           Butter
2   1           Cheese
3   1           Bread
```

Now when I run the following query it returns the recipe id = "1" even though it shouldn't because I don't want a recipe which has butter in it.

```
SELECT recipe.id
FROM 
  `recipe`
  INNER JOIN ingredients ON recipe.id = ingredients.recipeid
WHERE 
  (recipe.description LIKE '%CHEESE%' OR recipe.topic LIKE '%CHEESE%')
  AND (recipe.difficultylevel='Easy')
  AND (recipe.totaltime <= 30)
  AND (ingredients.ingredient <> 'Butter')
```

It returns recipe.id = "1" two times because of Cheese and Bread. I need to fix the query so that it excludes the recipe.id = "1" at all if it has Butter (for example)

Comment: Thank you @Michael for editing the question. Looks much easier to read. i really have no idea how to do that.

Comment: `select distinct`? as for formatting your code, just highlight it in the editor and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Use the `{}` editor toolbar button on highlighted code or `ctl-k` to format code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for help on how to format. SELECT DISTINCT will not work as it will still return recipe.id = "1" one time which it shouldn't at all

Comment: You're getting 1 back because your where clause is true when the ingredient is either Cheese or Bread. You need a different approach.

Comment: Yes I know that is the problem. How to change the query to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want the `inner join` if I'm understanding your question.  You could use an `outer join` with a `null` check, or you could use `not exists`:

```
select id
from recipe r
where 
    (recipe.description LIKE '%CHEESE%' OR recipe.topic LIKE '%CHEESE%')
    AND (recipe.difficultylevel='Easy')
    AND (recipe.totaltime <= 30)
    AND not exists (
        select 1
        from ingredients i
        where r.id = i.recipeid
             and i.ingredient = 'Butter'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you wasn't aware of 'NOT EXISTS' and 'EXISTS' methods.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that recipes including `Butter` are not in the output, you may use a `LEFT JOIN` including an `= 'Butter'` condition.  In the main query's `WHERE` clause,  you will want to look for `IS NULL` on a column for `ingredients` to ensure you get back *non* matches.

```
SELECT recipe.id
FROM
  recipe
  -- Join condition specifically looks for 'Butter' (other ingredients may be chained with OR inside () )
  LEFT JOIN ingredients ON recipe.id = ingredients.recipe_id AND (ingredient = 'Butter')
WHERE
  (recipe.description LIKE '%CHEESE%' OR recipe.topic LIKE '%CHEESE%')
  AND (recipe.difficultylevel='Easy')
  AND (recipe.totaltime <= 30)
  -- NULL condition for matching ingredient
  AND (ingredients.ingredient IS NULL)
```

And here's a demonstration, returning 1 recipe to match your criteria: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73f975/1

Comment: You beat me to the anti-join answer... +1 for you!

Comment: The solution works great but If I want a recipe which doesn't have 'butter1' but has 'cheese'. It should have returned 1 but it doesn't. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6c5c0/4/0

Comment: @SaadBashir It is not too difficult to modify the query that Michael has provided to suit your needs. He has answered your question adequately and now it is up to you to move forward with your own solution.